# Singleton Servlet instance

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

Tomcat makes the servlets as a singleton object, After then, sets this singleton object reference to connection threads as a local variable.  After then also, each thread play this local variable as syncronized. Is it right?

I confused, Because servlet is a singleton, so only one instance. But specification said that "do not mark service() method as a syncronized, because at that time the servlet container cannot use the instance pool approach.

Pool and singleton, very confusing in details. does the container uses "volatile" keyword to keep the shared local variebles equal in it's pool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A servlet is a singleton. That means that every request to that servlet calls the `service()` method of that single, unique object.

Making the `service()` method synchronized will thus work fine, except no two requests will ever be able to execute the `service()` method concurrently: that's what synchronized does.

So, instead of having 10 users each executing the method concurrently, you'll now have 1 user executing it, and 9 others waiting for the method to return, then the next one executing the method while the 8 others wait, etc. It will thus make the servlet very slow if you have concurrent requests, and will under-use the resources of your web server.

So, in short, your servlet must be thread-safe: it must allow for concurrent method executions, in a safe way.

Comment: Ok Servlet is a singleton, so only one. But why servlet specifications says "instance pool approach" ? Why container needs pool for one instance?

Comment: If the server was using a pool of (i.e. many) servlet instances instead of just one, then making the method synchronized would not be a problem: each request would use its own servlet instance from the pool. But it does NOT use a pool. Hence you should not make the method synchronized.

Comment: Even if there are one instance in the container, servlet container makes the instance more than one behind the scenes I thought.

Comment: If it did, it wouldn't be a singleton anymore.

Comment: What if, the computer which the container in has a 5 processor, also makes a only one instance?

Comment: Yes. That's the definition of a singleton. And that's why it's not a good idea to make it synchronized: only 1 of your processors would be busy, even if 20 requests want to execute the service method.